# "People persons" versus "people people"

Tags: grammar, plural-forms, register

A [People person](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/people%20person) is someone who is outgoing and has good communication skills.

> He was always energetic and positive and he was a **people person**.

What is the plural of "people person"?

I am thinking **People people** and **People persons**. However, I could not find any good source for either.

Comment: This is a relatively new coinage in English; it's been around for about 50 years or so.  **people persons** will do.  It is not a phrase that every native speaker feels comfortable using. It has a "morning TV" feel to it.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, what do you mean by "morning TV feel"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Grammarist says](http://grammarist.com/usage/people-persons/)

> In modern English, people is the [de facto](http://grammarist.com/usage/de-facto/) plural of person. People and person have separate Latin origins, and they came to English at different times by different paths, but there are examples of people used as a plural of person from as early as the 14th century. Persons was the original plural, and it is possible to find examples of its use in all types of writing up to the present, but it prevails only in a few contexts, most notably law and law enforcement, and in a few common phrases (e.g., persons of interest, displaced persons, missing persons). Elsewhere, it usually gives way to people.
>
> There is an old usage prescription holding that people applies to uncountable groups of individuals (e.g., Times Square was packed with people) while persons applies to groups that are easily counted (e.g., there were four persons on the balcony). But there is no good reason for this distinction, and in any case it is not consistently borne out in real-world usage.

The question I would ask in this situation is, **does *"people people"* sound right?**

I personally would say that it doesn't and would go for **people persons**.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to find information on the plural form of *people person*  from traditional dictionaries. However, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/people_person) gives the following entry for *people person*::

> Noun
>
> > **people person** (plural **people persons** or **people people**)
> >
> > > 1. (idiomatic) One who interacts skillfully with other people and who receives satisfaction from such interaction.

As you can see from the dictionary, people use both the terms *people persons* and *people people*. Both forms are used in printed books and magazines.

I prefer the term *people people* because *people person* is quite informal whereas the word *persons* is very formal. *People persons* seems to lose the warm informality of *people person*. That's just my preference, though.

Here is a quote from the website [Workopolis](https://careers.workopolis.com/advice/high-paying-jobs-for-people-who-dont-like-people/):

> Something we’re often expected to convey during a job interview is that we’re people people.